# OpenGL rendering GL_POINTS on iPhone/iPad devices looks horrible (but looks completely fine in the simulator)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios-simulator, points, glpointsize

I've created an OpenGL ES game which is being rendered using a GLKView on iOS. I've also added some custom UIButtons which are positioned on top of the GLKView. In the rendering I'm drawing some stars using the `GL_POINTS` rendering mode. Everything renders fine in the simulator but looks terrible on the device.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice as to things I should be configuring/looking out for on the device that may need to be set up in order to get the correct rendered image.

Here are a couple of images of the results:

***Simulator***

[image: Screenshot of game running on iPhone simulator.]

***Device***

[image]

(Please ignore the difference in scaling of the custom buttons - the device screenshot was taken on an iPad).

Comment: Are you using `glClearColor()` and `glClear()` to initialize your drawing space before rendering? If not, you might be picking up previously existing artifacts.

Comment: Hey Brad, I double checked this and my glClearColor/glClear seems to be being called and doing the right thing. I think if the issue was to do with this then I would see the same result in the simulator too, but thanks for the suggestion - it was something to check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was to do with not setting `gl_PointSize` in the shader for OpenGL ES. The screenshots actually led me to this solution because the stars (drawn using the `GL_POINTS` rendering mode) are so radically wrong on the device than on the simulator.

Presumably for the desktop version of OpenGL, the point size is set using the `glPointSize` function by default (unless `GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` is enabled). On OpenGL ES there is no `glPointSize` function, so the point size value must always be specified using the built-in `gl_PointSize` variable in the vertex shader.

Comment: How can I do this if I'm using the GLKBaseEffect from GLKit?

Comment: I don't think you can - you have to write the shader.

Comment: Avoid `GLKBaseEffect`. It tries to imitate the fixed function pipeline, just learn how shaders work and use them directly. To be honest I'm not sure why they built `GLKBaseEffect` or its derivative classes.